# date value is converted from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy while converting excel to html using aspose.cells for java

Tags: aspose-cells

I have a cell in excel formatted as date with value '31-03-2017' but when I am exporting the excel to html it is getting converted to '31/03/2017'.

'03-31-2017' again a date formatted cell but coming up as expected, if I have to speculate looks like there is a problem with dd-MM-yyyy format.

I am using "aspose-cells-8.7.0" library.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Code snippet

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(new FileInputStream(new File("filePath")));
workbook.calculateFormula();
HtmlSaveOptions htmlSaveOptions = new HtmlSaveOptions();
htmlSaveOptions.setPresentationPreference(true);
htmlSaveOptions.setParseHtmlTagInCell(false);
htmlSaveOptions.setExportHiddenWorksheet(false);
workbook.save("outputPath", htmlSaveOptions);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Such issue occurs because of **Language and Region Settings** of your machine i.e. OS (Operating System). Please see the following screenshot. You can change your region and country and number and date formats from such interfaces.

[image]

Now, whenever you will change your region or language, your dates will look different because your dates are in built-in formats and they don't have custom formats.

In order to test this, please change the region and open your Excel file in Microsoft Excel and you will see, your dates now look different.

It means, you should load your workbook with the correct region and language settings. Here is the sample code for your reference. Please read its comments.

**Java**

```
//Please load your workbook with correct Language and Region - Country Code
LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
loadOptions.setLanguageCode(CountryCode.USA);
loadOptions.setRegion(CountryCode.USA);

//Pass the load options while loading workbook
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(new FileInputStream(new File("filePath")), loadOptions);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I understand Locale plays a role especially for built in date functions, if such is the case I expect it to change from dd-MM-yyyy(Indian) to MM-dd-yyyy(American). The problem here is it is changing the delimiters as I stated  (- to /). However I will check what you suggested and update here mean while if you happen to find anything more kindly update, thanks.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but the behavior is the same, Location and region are set correctly

Comment: I think, it should solve your issue. Just create a date in new Excel file using Microsoft Excel and then  execute the code given by me by setting different regions and language like French, Brazil, Germany, Japan, China etc. and then save the file to Pdf or Html and will see, dates formats are getting changed. This should not just happen in Aspose.Cells, Microsoft Excel will also show dates differently whenever you change the language and region. Thank you and regards.

Comment: This is an issue in the apose version(aspose-cells-8.7.0) I am using which is fixed from the version "8.9.2", Thanks for the help